# Positioning a hide/show div relative to trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

I'm struggling to find the right Jquery to show/hide a div at a height that is parallel to the trigger button. I attempted to offset the show/hide div to the right, but because the footnotes appear in different left/right positioning, each would be different. Instead, I will need to place the divs inside of another div along the right.

My hope is to add hyperlinked footnotes to some text, so that readers will not have to search for the footnotes, but also won't be overwhelmed with too much text. I would prefer to have more than one footnote open at a time, but if it needs to be one at a time to properly display, so be it.

EDIT:

@rohan-kumar helped with this code

```
$('.a_footnote').on('click',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var divId=$(this).data('divid');
console.log(divId);
$('#'+divId).toggle();
});
```

So here's the way it stands: http://jsfiddle.net/6n28t/21/

However, my primary problem remains -- how can I make the footnote appear at the same height as the trigger? These will be long pieces of text and I want the footnotes to appear at the same height as the corresponding mark. How can I made [2] appear farther down on the page?

Comment: Do you want to hide `div#footnote1` on clicking on `a#footnote1`. Right?

Comment: $(this).closest('.content').next('.footnotes').toggle();

Comment: Your markup is incorrect, you have specified `id="footnote1"` twice, which is incorrect since id's need to be unique.

Comment: If you start getting into complexities then it is worth considering a plugin like http://stevenbenner.github.io/jquery-powertip/ which would handle cases like when the link is on the very edge of the right hand viewport and would otherwise be hidden

Answer (score 1):

So, basically combining the other answers leads to this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6n28t/26/)**

Html is the same as what you have in your fiddle.

**CSS**

```
.wrapp{
    border:1px solid red;
    height:100%;
}

.clear{
    clear:both;
}

.footnotes div {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.a_footnote').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var divId=$(this).data('divid');
    var height = $(this).position().top;
    console.log(divId);
    $(".footnotes div").hide();
    $('#'+divId).toggle().css("top", height - 10);
});
```

Comment: YES. Thank you. I'm not sure what I was doing, but I couldn't get the positioning correct. This is great!

Comment: Note that if you want to get the footnotes to stick around when you click a different one, you'll need to recompute their heights.

Comment: For anyone else who will be using this -- do note that you will need to change the height offset number (-10 here) to the number of pixels above the start of the "wrapp" div. It took me a long time to notice and figure out the problem!

Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapp">
    <div class="content" style="float:left;">
        <div> Lorem ipsum (<a class="a_footnote" href='javascript:;' data-divid="footnote1">[1]</a>).</div>
    </div>
    <div class="footnotes" style="float:right">
        <div id="footnote1">1. Foo Bar</div>
    </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapp{
    border:1px solid red;
    height:50px;
}
.clear{
    clear:both;
}
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$('.a_footnote').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var divId=$(this).data('divid');
    console.log(divId);
    $('#'+divId).toggle();
});
```

If you want the `div.footnotes` will be `hidden` initially, then you need to add a `css` like

```
div.footnotes {display:none;}
```

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/6n28t/7

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to have the footnotes hidden on load and then appear at the same height as the trigger. This code places the footnotes at the top of the footnotes div, regardless of the trigger location.

Comment: @user2429096 Check the above answer I've made changes in it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the floats, I am assuming that you would want this text to appear inline in your paragraphs. You need to position the notes absolutely and then set the top/left according to the position of your clicked element + width of element + offset.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CRkdx/3/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="content">
    <p> Lorem ipsum (<a href="#" class="footnote" id="footnote1">[1]</a>).</p>
    <p> Lorem ipsum (<a href="#" class="footnote" id="footnote2">[2]</a>).</p>
</div>

<div class="footnotes">
    <div class="footnote1">1. Foo Bar</div>
    <div class="footnote2">2. Foo Bar</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.footnotes > div { display: none; position: absolute; border: solid 1px red; }
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.footnote').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $note = $('.' + this.id);
    var $position = $(this).position();
    $('.footnotes > div').hide();
    $note.css({
        top : $position.top,
        left: $position.left + $(this).width() + 5
    }).show(); })
```

Comment: I would actually prefer that the footnotes aren't displayed inline, but in a div along the right side of the screen.

Comment: At the same level as the original link? Let me know and I'll update my code, it's just a matter of css postioning.

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/CRkdx/5/ Clicking again will hide the footnote, css controls color/width etc